# Default value of column removed after move

Tags: phpmyadmin, null, default, move, alter

I have 3 columns and I set "family" as NULL:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| ID | name  | family |
+----+-------+--------+
```

mysql>test

```
CREATE TABLE `test` 
( 
    `id` INT NOT NULL , 
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    `family` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[image: Inline image]

Then in use "move" link to move "name" after "family"

[image]

This cause default value of "family" column to be removed!

- phpMyAdmin Version : 4.9.1
- Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.0

Why did this happen?

Comment: Could you please let us know which phpMyAdmin version you're using?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this without luck; once the table is created I'm going to the table's Structure tab, then the "Move columns" link where I drag to re-order the columns. I've tried with several phpMyAdmin versions and have no problems. Could you also please tell us your database type (MySQL, MariaDB, etc) and version?